# css - How to show 100px of an image

Tags: html, css

I need to show just `100px` of `height` of an image but it's not work.
I don't want to damage the image. Just show 100px of an image.

```css
.image-news
  {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .image-news img
  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 no-padding">
              <div class="image-news">
                <img src="http://blog.emania.com.br/content/uploads/2015/12/paisagem-tropical-wallpaper-1.jpg"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 no-padding content-news">
              <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <div class="title">
                  <span>Title</span>
                </div>
              </a>
              <div class="content">
                <span>Content</span>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove `height` of `img` and then give `overflow:hidden` to `.image-news`

```css
.image-news {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-news img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 no-padding">
  <div class="image-news">
    <img src="http://blog.emania.com.br/content/uploads/2015/12/paisagem-tropical-wallpaper-1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 no-padding content-news">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Title</span>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="content">
    <span>Content</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is possible use background-position? How? @Alex

Comment: @user3242861 Yes, it is.

Comment: How can i do that? @Alex

Comment: but i have to use img tag. I get the links from database. @Alex

Comment: @user3242861 There are several way to set `background-image` such as   internal or inlne css.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139885/discussion-between-alex-and-user3242861).